# Fragment NavHostFragment did not create a view

Tags: android, navigation, androidx

I couldn’t catch this problem personally, but there are a lot of such errors on Firebase Crashlytics

[image]

I tried all the answers with StackOverflow but nothing helped

[image]

My R.layout.activity_main

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph"/>
```

My navigation/main_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tols"
    xmlns:tools2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/ordersFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ordersFragment"
        android:name="com.app.package.ui.orders.view.OrdersFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_orders"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_orders">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_ordersFragment_to_orderFragment"
        app:destination="@id/orderFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_ordersFragment_to_problemFragment"
        app:destination="@id/problemFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_ordersFragment_to_settingsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/problemFragment"
        android:name="com.app.package.ui.problem.ProblemFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_problems" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderFragment"
        android:name="com.app.package.ui.order.view.OrderFragment"
        android:label="OrderFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_orderFragment_to_compositionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/compositionFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_orderFragment_to_selectCheckDialog"
        app:destination="@id/selectCheckDialog" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/compositionFragment"
        android:name="com.app.package.ui.composition.CompositionFragment"
        android:label="fragment_composition"
        tools2:layout="@layout/fragment_composition" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.app.package.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_settings"
        tools2:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectCheckDialog"
        android:name="com.app.package.ui.order.view.SelectCheckDialog"
        android:label="dialog_select_check"
        tools2:layout="@layout/dialog_select_check" />
</navigation>
```

My gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0'
```

I tried different solutions but nothing helped. 
Judging by Firebase Crashlytics 963 crash in 342 users.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Encountered this when tried to rotate the phone, while using the application.

This happened to me because I was using `Fragment` transactions in `onCreate`, even though `nav_graph.xml` handles that for us.

I just changed:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
            .commitNow()
    }
}
```

to:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

First of all, what is the source of this issue?
If the app remains in the background for a while android will destroy the activities that are in the back stack. So here are some possible steps:

- User opens the app
- Navigate to another activity from the MainActivity
- Put the app in the background
- Come back after a while
- Navigate back to MainActivity
- CRASH

You can reproduce it easier if you check the "Don't keep activities" option
in "Developer Option"

Possible fix: Replace `fragment` tag from activity_main with `FragmentContainerView`but at least for me this generates other issues.

Answer (score 1):

in Manifest:

```
  activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in a new template-created project because I added the host fragment inside a `DrawerLayout` without thinking about the `include` for the app bar which has an `include` for content where there's another host fragment. It was a facepalm moment. I was copying pieces of code from an existing project to speed things up and went a bit too far there.

Removing either host fragment fixed the crash. Changing the id of one of them also fixed the crash, but then the nav graph was inflated twice. Of course, I wanted to use the one in the app bar content instead of the one I added.

It looks like your `activity_main` layout is much simpler if that's the whole thing, but check to make sure it's not possible for a layout to include more than one host fragment with the same id.